# PrintWriter not printing texts to .txt file

Tags: java, text, editor, printwriter

This program asks for the output filename and seems to work good. Until I try to open the output file with a text editor or terminal. Then I don't see anything in that file just blank file. This program creates the text file but the file is empty. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
/**
 * Writes a Memo file.
 * 
 */
public class MemoPadCreator {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Output file name: ");
    String filename = console.nextLine();
  try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(filename);

    boolean done = false;
    while (!done) {
      System.out.println("Memo topic (enter -1 to end):");
      String topic = console.nextLine();
      // Once -1 is entered, memo's will no longer be created.
      if (topic.equals("-1")) {
        done = true;
     console.close();
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Memo text:");
        String message = console.nextLine();

        /* Create the new date object and obtain a dateStamp */
        Date now = new Date();
        String dateStamp = now.toString();

        out.println(topic + "\n" + dateStamp + "\n" + message);
      }
   }
    /* Close the output file */

  } catch (IOException exception) {
    System.out.println("Error processing the file:" + exception);
  }console.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `out.flush()` for flushing the contents to the file.

Or use auto-flush constructor of [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter%28java.io.Writer%29) (**may not be the best performing option**) but is anyway an option

```
public PrintWriter(Writer out,boolean autoFlush)
```

> autoFlush - A boolean; if `true`, the `println`, `printf`, or format methods
>   will flush the output buffer

Comment: @MirkoAdari yes true but the current program does not seem to require performance. Thats why I suggested it. Anyways a valid point will include it in the post.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't close your `PrintWriter` object. You need to close the stream to reflect it on console or file (depending upon your outputStream)

```
out.close();
```

Even if you have

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
...
...
...
out.close();
```

Then you need to close it so the output is written on console.
So in your case closing the stream will write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to flush the `PrintWriter` for the contents to be written into the file from memory buffer.

```
out.flush();
```

In any case you should also always close (release) the resources, as otherwise locks can or will remain on the file, depending on the OS. And `close()` also flushes the changes automatically.